# Crystal Reports Issue with Logo Suppressions

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-8.5

I've been having an issue I'm looking at with crystal reports for my organization. I have two logos. The first logo is currently looking at a supression code:

```
{JCCM.Department} <> '01' and
{JCCM.Department} <> '02' and
{JCCM.Department} <> '10' and
{JCCM.Department} <> '16'
```

While the second logo is

```
{JCCM.Department} <> '11' and
{JCCM.Department} <> '15'
```

The problem I am running into is on reports with Department 10 the Logo should be 1 but it is pulling 2. It's almost as if it is breaking on the code when you get to 10 but then department for 16 pulls the correct logo being logo 1 so that kind of ruled it out. Any suggestions?